# Automated controller for outdoor use

Tags: automation

I need a recommendation on a controller to use, which will automatically cause a water flushing system to turn on and off at certain times. I have played around with a [LOGO!](http://w3.siemens.com/mcms/programmable-logic-controller/en/logic-module-logo/pages/default.aspx) PLC but it is turning out to be very restrictive.
Some qualifications:

- Low power usage: the controller only needs to log data every hour or so. It is powered by a solar panel and a battery and cannot draw too much electricity (especially during the winter).
- A way to configure flushing times. This either could be an attachable/onboard display and interface, or a way to connect externally. If going with the latter, it should act as a simple server and respond to commands, or host a webserver
- The ability to log data and export it, over a network or onto external storage.

Bonus point for...

- An integrated way to connect to a cell network (using a sim card)
- Being really small!

Any advice or recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're really good at programming check out the Raspberry Pi

Comment: The raspberry pi is practically a full blown computer which makes me worried about power consumption. I havn't looked that up though could be wrong

Comment: The Pi doesn't draw that much power, and once it is configured you can down clock the CPU for further power savings.  A lot of the power usage for the Pi is people connecting power drawing devices to all 4 USB ports.

Comment: As cybernard has said it draws very little power. At normal clock speed and a USB wifi dongle attached, my Pi 2 Model B draws about 100mA at 5V when idle and up to 1A when under load.

Comment: alright ill consider it as an option then!